# Does the category with two objects, one arrow exist?

Tags: category-theory

According to pg. 10 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, there exists a category called $\mathbf{2}$ s.t.

> $\mathbf{2}$ is the category with two objects $a$, $b$ and just one arrow $a \rightarrow b$ not the identity

But doesn't this violate the axiom that all categories must have, for each object, an identity arrow?  Here there is no identity arrow $id_a$ and $id_b$, which seems to suggest that $\mathbf{2}$ is in fact not a category.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a wording issue. The phrase "just one arrow $a\rightarrow b$ not the identity" means that the category has only one *non-identity* arrow; so this is a category with *three* arrows total, the identities on $a$ and $b$ and the unique $a\rightarrow b$. (Note that the non-identity arrows determine the entire category!)

It would probably be clearer to write it as "just one arrow *which* is not *an* identity", but oh well.